# Cannot create Blob Container with Azure's REST API

Tags: c#, rest, azure, xamarin, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to create a Blob Container using C# and the REST API (in Xamarin.Android).  I'm able to upload a blob to an existing container, but I can't seem to create a container via REST. The error is **(403) Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.**  Creating the Authorization Header works when uploading a blob, so it must be something with the way I'm constructing the container's string to be signed, but for the life of me I can't find the problem.  Here's the code:

```
    private async Task<bool> CreateContainer(string containerName)
    {          
        String requestMethod = "PUT";
        String msVersion = "2009-09-19";
        string dt = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        String canonicalizedHeaders = String.Format("x-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-version:{1}", dt, msVersion);
        String canonicalizedResource = String.Format("/{0}/{1}\nrestype:container", AzureStorageConstants.Account, containerName);
        String stringToSign = String.Format("{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}", requestMethod, canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource);

        string auth = SignThis(stringToSign);   
        string urlPath = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}?restype=container", AzureStorageConstants.Account, containerName);
        Uri uri = new Uri(urlPath);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", dt);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2009-09-19");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);

        HttpContent empty = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(uri, empty);

        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }

    private static String SignThis(String StringToSign)
    {
        String signature = string.Empty;
        byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(AzureStorageConstants.Key);
        using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
        {
            Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StringToSign);
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
        }

        String authorizationHeader = String.Format(
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
              "{0} {1}:{2}",
              "SharedKey",
              AzureStorageConstants.Account,
              signature);

        return authorizationHeader;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your request is failing is because you're not including the content length in your `stringToSign` even though it is included in the request (HttpClient is including it and setting its value to `0`). This is causing signature to mismatch. To fix this, include content length in your `stringToSign`:

```
String stringToSign = String.Format("{0}\n\n\n0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}", requestMethod, canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource);
```